# return AJAX result for each cURL Request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

Basically, my idea is to do some form of "**live cURL results**" system which is producing **live results** when each request is performed, for example I'll have a table with a list of websites that need to be accessed via a cURL request in which upon the result of each cURL response I need data to be sent back to my page using the AJAX Function I initially made the call to the file which performs this loop of requests

```
<?
    foreach($database['table'] as $row) {
       curl_init($row['url']);
       //the rest of the cURL request etc...

       //SEND cURL RESPONSE BACK TO AJAX AFTER EACH ROW!!!
    }
<?
```

I then want it to return the result for each **cURL** response as they happen, instead of waiting for the full script to complete before returning them all at once.

Is this possible? if so would I still use a normal **AJAX** request?

Comment: AJAX is client-side, by JavaScript. cURL is server-side, by PHP. What do you want? You should also note that your `curl_init()` will return a resource handle, which you should use a variable to save it.

Comment: You can flush() any results you get if that helps, but as Shivan Raptor said, they are two different technologies so it's hard to say, unless you are going to spam your "API" with AJAX requests to check every < 1s to check for updated results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

You break down the entie process into 3

**Process 1**

You send an ajax request to the php page that access the database and send back the list of urls to the browser page. [simply echo the Urls ] [use a separator '|' to separate the result urls.]

**Process 2**

The ajax success handler function of the above process will now call a new JavaScript function that does the below.

split the url list int an array.

**Process 3**
Send the urls list one by one to the server using a another ajax function.

This way only One url is processed at once and results are send back as soon as it is processed

Below is the prototype of function calls in JavaScript, the code is not real, but you get an overall idea about how it works.

```
function ajaxCall_1()
{
    // get url lsit from server
    .onSuccess{
        process_url(data);
    }
}


function process_url(data){
    var url_array = data.split('|')

    fetch_urls(url_array,0); // sends the first url for processing
}

function fetch_urls(url_array,position){

  if(position < url_array.lenght){ // not exceeding the array count 
    ajax_call2(url_array[position],url_array,position); 
  }
}

function ajaxCall_2(url,url_array,position)
{
    // get url acced by  curl and send back the result
    .onSuccess{
        // do whatever with the data you want
        fetch_urls(url_array,position++) // or position+1 // to fetch the next url
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the php script that builds that table of website, simply do your ajax requests all at once and return the result to your table rows as they come back.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return messages as you write them, unless you're writing to a socket.
In normal AJAX calls to a PHP script, this is not possible, and you can only write the response once and return it.

Comment: This is false. AJAX features `readyState == 3`, which is `incomplete` and provides you with all the contents that the server has sent to your client before the request has finished. This can also be used, for example, to control download speed, simply by flushing the desired amount of data within a certain time interval.

Comment: It's not AJAX the problem, but the PHP part, in that it is not possible to output data as he processes the rows from the database. PHP outputs everything at once.

Comment: Which is still incorrect. PHP has the possibility to flush data to a client even before it's done. As a matter of fact, it does so automatically unless you use something like the output buffer, which prevents it from sending contents. Try setting a header after a single line of HTML and it will even tell you itself that it cannot modify headers once data was sent. Using output buffers, it would be possible to use `ob_flush()` and all other methods using this one, like `ob_end_flush()`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use `flush` or `ob_flush`.
This commands will force send outputed data to browser, but in some cases it can be stopped in a middle software (nginx for example)

And there is another problem. Untill your script sending data, page will not fires loaded event. So many js scripts will not work.

In your case I will make another system.

1. Your script with curl running from crontab one in a short time.
2. All results from curl are saved in database.
3. Ajax script calls php backend that outputs last results and delete them from database.

This will work in any case (mostly) :)

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to achieve your goal.

1. Do separate AJAX requests for each cURL request. This way you won't have to "find a tricky solution", everything will work as it is supposed to
2. Use `curl_multi_*` to perform all requests simultaneously and then return all data in one big batch. This way you open your script to potential load issues in case there are many users doing many requests simultaneously

I used both of them in different projects and can provide more details on each if you need any.

Answer (score 1):

Well i actually didn't get what you wants to do i think [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) will help you out
[Web Sockets Tutorail](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the results of the curl request one by one and retrieve that by doing a request after every **N** seconds (assume 5 seconds).

In this part we are storing the output of a curl request somewhere.Here goes a bit modified source code of yours which is grabbing the output and calling a function to store it in the queue :

```
//these two lines will be mostly same for all request
//so i put them out of the loop
curl_init($ch); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//these two lines will be mostly same for all request
//so i put them out of the loop
curl_init($ch); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

foreach($database['table'] as $row) {
    // set URL and other appropriate options which
    //vaires from request to requeste
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $row['url']);
    //grabbing the output in $output
    $output = $curl_exec();
    put_it_to_the_queue($output);
}
curl_exec($ch);
```

Now what will `put_it_to_the_queue($output)` will do ? It will store the output somewhere so that some other resource can fetch them from there. For simplicity's sake lets put that in your session.

```
function put_it_to_the_queue($output) {
    //Or you can store in sql lite or in a file or somewhere else
    array_push($_SESSION['outputs']);
}
```

Question is how the client will cope up with this different situation.

Let the client give the first call to the server to start fetching the urls and completely forget about that.

```
$.get('start.php');
```

And we need to get the output . How to achieve this ? Create another php page `pull.php` for that which will send the output if he has anything in the queue.

```
echo array_shift($_SESSION['outputs']);
```

And here is the client side code to retrieve the outputs.
Place this code after sending the first request to the server.

```
//delay is in ms
//5 is the value of N seconds 
//we will retrieve the output form
var delay = 5 * 1000;
window.setInterval(function(){
    $.get('pull.php',function(response){
        //do something with the reponse here
        alert(response);
    })
}, delay);
```

### Note

***This solution is not fool proof. If you have a heavy hear website you need to use more precised storage to store the result of the html request and you need to use push approach rather than pull approach in that case.***

To know more about the functions i have used here :

1. [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)
2. [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)
3. [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)

Answer (score 0):

Concept of Ajax request to PHP script is, when you make Ajax call, it executes requested PHP script and whole response send by to Ajax.

according to your requirement, PHP script wont sent part of response to Ajax call, instead PHP script can send collection of cUrl response at once.

To solve this problem you can do following steps

1. Create two action in PHP and Two Ajax call.
2. One action to send all URls from Table to first Ajax call.
3. After getting first response (list of URLS) you can execute series
   of Ajax call (in a loop for each fetched URls).
4. This Ajax call will request for Second PHP script which execute cUrl
   to fetch reponse.
5. Then you send this response back to initiated Ajax call. then do what you wanted to do with that cUrl response.

Hope it will help you.