# Update page after each cURL Request

Tags: php, curl

I have the following code:

```
$fiz = $_GET['file'];
    $file = file_get_contents($fiz);
    $trim = trim($file);
    $tw = explode("\n", $trim);
    $browser = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1468.0 Safari/537.36';
    foreach($tw as $twi){
        $url = 'https://twitter.com/users/username_available?username='.$twi;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '$browser');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $json = json_decode($result, true);
        if($json['valid'] == 1){
        echo "Twitter ".$twi." is available! <br />";
        $fh = fopen('available.txt', 'a') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, $twi."\n");
    } else {
        echo "Twitter ".$twi." is taken! <br />";
    }
}
```

And what it does is that it takes list that would look something like:

apple

dog

cat

and so on, and it checks it with Twitter to check if the name is taken or not.
What I want to know is that if it's in any way possible to make the request show up after each check in instead of showing up all at once?

Comment: perhaps ajax each request and append a list with the results after each call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Ajax calls, If you are familiar with JavaScript or Jquery you can easily do this.

Instead of checking all names at once , use an Ajax function to send one name at a time to the server side PHP code.

Say you send "Cat" first , the page is processed and returns the result using Ajax. Now you can display the result on page.

send "dog" get the response---> display it and so on.

A similar Question has been answered here [Return AJAX result for each cURL Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648521/return-ajax-result-for-each-curl-request/19886764)

Hope this helps, I use Jquery here ...

**JavaScript**

```
<script>

 var keyArray = ('cat','dog','mouse','rat');

 function checkUserName(name, keyArray, position){
  $("#result").load("namecheck.php", {uesername: name, function(){ // Results are displayed on 'result' element
    fetchNext(keyArray, position);
  });}
 }

 function fetchNext(keyArray, position){
   position++; // get next name in the array
   if(position < keyArray.lenght){ // not exceeding the aray count
     checkUserName(keyArray[position], keyArray, position) // make ajax call to check user name 
   }
 }

 function startProcess(){
  var keyArray = ('cat','dog','mouse','rat');
  var position = 0; // get the first element from the array
  fetchNext(keyArray, position); 
 }

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="result"></div>

<button onclick="startProcess()"> Start Process </button>
```

**PHP**

```
<?
        $twi = $_GET['username'];

        $browser = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1468.0 Safari/537.36';
        $url = 'https://twitter.com/users/username_available?username='.$twi;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '$browser');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $json = json_decode($result, true);

        if($json['valid'] == 1){
          echo "Twitter ".$twi." is available! <br />";
          $fh = fopen('available.txt', 'a') or die("can't open file");
          fwrite($fh, $twi."\n");
        }else{
          echo "Twitter ".$twi." is taken! <br />";
        } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, would it be possible for you to give me a good example for my code I provided?

Comment: Just added code example to may answer, Your PHP code has been modified a little to match my code.

Comment: Did you check this method? did that help you?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it doesn't seem to be working however. [Here](http://textbarrage.com/twi.php) is my website I've used your code on. And here is the source for that page: http://pastebin.com/L7v3tEFV

Comment: You need to use the PHP code in a separate file [namecheck.php] and you base file is index.html where the HTMl and JavaScript resides. That is how Ajax works.... your code on paste-bin have php inside your HTML code. Please learn the basics of Ajax so that you can better understand the concepts.